# Find & Replace åäö Letters in Image links using mysql query Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace

I moved my WordPress website to another server and got a problem with some of the images not showing up, i noticed the problem is that those images are using Swedish letters åäö in them, so i renamed them all using "Bulk Rename Utility" replacing å and ä with a, and ö with o.

But remaining is that i need to rename the image links in WordPress db to make this all correct.

Can someone please help me with a query for mass replacing these letters in the images? My images are all .jpg

Thanks

Comment: Renaming those files was already a mistake. I would recommend to keep the filenames as they are and fix the links/image sources instead. Everything has worked once, after all, so the only think you need to get right is the data transfer from the old to the new server.

Comment: the link sources images works perfectly fine, but i have read that using åäö in image filenames is not so good and doesnt always work on all servers.

Comment: FUD. Of course that works, it only needs to be done right. Don't clobber your data prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field =  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(your_field, 'å', 'a'),'ä','a'),'ö','o');
```

Comment: thanks for the query, iam not so good with mysql, but i guess the correct table where the image names are is in "wp_postmeta", your field i dont know what to input there.

Doesnt the query replace everything having åäö in the table? i only need to replace it on the images.

Comment: If image link/name is stored as post meta field then yes. If so, your field should be meta_value and you should add where clause like `where meta_key='key_of_meta_with_image'`. Tell me name of post meta field and I'll update answer to reflect it.

Comment: If the images are embedded in posts then the link is just html stored in `PREFIX_posts.post_content`.